# Mismatched tag error in Python minidom parser

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, minidom

I'm using Python's `minidom` to parse a document such as:

```
<root>
  <foo>This tag contains a "<bar>" string</foo>
</root>
```

The `"<bar>"` string causes a `xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: mismatched tag` exception.

Is there a way to solve this without hacking the input file?

Answer (score 1):

By "hacking the input file" you appear to mean "making my HTML conformant". The opening "<" of "<bar>" should be HTML-encoded as "&lt;". How is the parser supposed to know that it genuinely isn't an HTML tag otherwise?